# Many to "two" relationship adding extra FK (also not working)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following classes

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; protected set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

with the following (presumably incorrect) mappings

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.HasMany(x => x.Bars);
    }
}

public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.References(x => x.Foo1);
        this.References(x => x.Foo2);
    }
}
```

When creating the tables, FNH is doing the following:

```
create table "Bar" (
    Id  integer primary key autoincrement,
   Foo1_id INT,
   Foo2_id INT,
   Foo_id INT,
   constraint FK52E419EE7F0CDD3 foreign key (Foo1_id) references "Foo",
   constraint FK52E419EE3C0DCDD3 foreign key (Foo2_id) references "Foo",
   constraint FK52E419EE34BDF7FF foreign key (Foo_id) references "Foo"
)
```

i.e. has an extra FK reference.

This means that calling `someBar.Foo1` is fine, but calling `soFoo.Bars` is always empty.

I've looked into using

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Bars).KeyColumns.Add("Foo1_id", "Foo2_id");
```

but this returns the error:

> Foreign key (FK52E419EE660E4A59:Bar [Foo1_id, Foo2_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Foo [Id]).

What is the correct way to map this form of relationship?

---

To clarify the expected result if we have

```
Table:Foos   |  Table:Bars
Id           |  Id    Foo1_id   Foo2_id
--           |  -----------------------
11           |  1     11        12
12           |  2     12        11
13           |  3     12        13
```

then `this.Session.Get<Foo>(11).Bars` should contain `Bar`s with `Id` of `1` and `2`.

Comment: How does Foo.Bars know which of the 2 choices it should reference?  (Or rather, what are you expecting Foo.Bars to contain? )

Comment: @granadaCoder Thanks for the response. I've updated the question with expected output.

Comment: Can you make the 1's and 2's unambiguous?  Like, Bars.Id, not be 1 2 3 ?

Comment: @granadaCoder I'm not sure I understood your question but I've updated the Q with less similar keys for clarity - is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes...so one doesn't have to go "which '1' is he talking about?"....the changes met that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do what you are asking, with the auto-"merge voodoo" of the Foo.Bars (thus my question in the comments of the question).

I think this is what you can do.  Note, I've come up with something a little less generic than Foo and Bar.

I have a "Project".  And an Employee.  Each Employee can "own" or "work-on" a project (or both).  Obviously, in the real world this would be dumb to force an employee to only own or work on a single project.
But it works here.

The Project has (many) Owners and Workers.  And I have a get(readonly get) property for Anyone-associated-with-the-project.  That is where you merge the two distinct relationships.

I have no idea on the Lazy-Initialization with this.  I'm just pointing that the auto-merge thing you're looking for.. probably isn't in the cards.

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual int ProjectKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> ProjectOwners { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> ProjectWorkers { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Employee> AnybodyAssociatedWithThisProject 
    {
        get
        {
            List<Employee> returnItems = new List<Employee>();
            if (null != this.ProjectOwners)
            {
                returnItems.AddRange(this.ProjectOwners);
            }
            if (null != this.ProjectOwners)
            {
                returnItems.AddRange(this.ProjectWorkers);
            }
            return returnItems;
        }
    }
}


public class Employee
{
    public virtual int EmployeeKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string SSN { get; set; }
    public virtual Project OwnedProject { get; set; }
    public virtual Project WorkedOnProject { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectMap : ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ProjectKey);
        Map(x => x.ProjectName);
        HasMany(x => x.ProjectOwners)
            .KeyColumn("OwnedProjectKey");
        HasMany(x => x.ProjectWorkers)
            .KeyColumn("WorkedOnProjectKey");
        Table("Project");
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.EmployeeKey);
        Map(x => x.SSN);
        References(x => x.OwnedProject).Column("OwnedProjectKey");
        References(x => x.WorkedOnProject).Column("WorkedOnProjectKey");
        Table("Employee");
    }
}
```

I tested some data.
Everything seems to work.  The one caveat is that if an Employee "owns" and "works-on" a Project, my simple ".AddRange" merge code will duplicate that Employee.
Other than that, it looks solid.

Comment: Okay, cool this makes sense. I'll make those collections protected and expose an aggregate of the two. Thanks for your help.